# How to bind generic type of static nested class from a static factory method?

Tags: java, generics

I'm playing with a variant of the Builder pattern outlined in [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/) and I'm getting confused by the behavior of Java generics.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Result<T extends Resource> {
    //final members
    final boolean success;
    final T resource;

    //private constructor
    private Result(Builder<T> builder) {
        success = builder.success;
        resource = builder.resource;
    }

    //getters
    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
    public T getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    //static factory method to get a builder
    public static <T2 extends Resource> Builder<T2> builder(Class<T2> clazz) {
        return new Builder<T2>();
    }

    //nested Builder class
    public static class Builder<T extends Resource> {
        boolean success;
        T resource;

        private Builder() { }

        public Builder<T> success(boolean success) {
            this.success = success;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder<T> resource(T resource) {
            this.resource = resource;
            return this;
        }

        public Result<T> build() {
            return new Result<T>(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work well when I have a concrete subclass of Resource:

```
Result<Device> result = Result.builder(Device.class).build();
```

However, when I use it from another class that defines a method with a generic subclass of Resource, it fails to even compile:

```
public <T extends Resource> Result<T> createResult(T resource) {
    return Result.builder(resource.getClass()).build();
}
```

The compile error is:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Result<capture#1-of ? extends Resource> to Result<T>

Since both T and T2 extend Resource, why can't it figure out that Result.Builder.build() should return a Result with generic type T?

One workaround I found is to ditch the static builder() method and use something like this instead:

```
public <T extends Resource> Result<T> createResult(T resource) {
    return new Result.Builder<T>().build();
}
```

It just seems like there should be a way to do it with the static factory method and hidden constructor...am I missing something?

Comment: Interestingly, it works if I update the static `builder()` method to accept an instance of type T2 (instead of just its class):

    `public static <T2 extends Resource> Builder<T2> builder(T2 dummy) {
        return new Builder<T2>();
    }`

But it seems a bit silly to force users to pass a dummy instance of T just to get the generics to work.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the builder hierarchies used in Spring Boot, particularly the `HttpSecurity` builder. The generics can get a bit twisty but do solve the problem you're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the compile error is due to `Object.getClass()` method. According to the java doc:

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.
>
> **The actual result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.** For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> Number n = 0;
>   Class c = n.getClass();

When calling `return Result.builder(resource.getClass()).build();`

1. `resource.getClass()` will return **`Class<? extends Resource>`** as `Resource` is the erasure of `T`
2. `Result.builder(resource.getClass())` method will return **`Builder<? extends Resource>`**.
3. `Result.builder(resource.getClass()).build()` will return **`Result<? extends Resource>`**.

The type information for `T` is lost in step 1. Hence compile error is shown as return type is incompatible. The following changes can be made to solve the error.

1. Change the builder method to accept `T` instance instead of `Class<T>` as state in your comment.
2. Change the caller to pass `Class<T>` instead of `Class<? extends Resource>` to `builder` method.

Code snippet for the changes:

```
  // Caller
  // Solution 1
  public <T extends Resource> Result<T> createResult(T resource) {
    return Result.builder(resource).build();
  }

  // Solution 2
  public <T extends Resource> Result<T> createResult(Class<T> resourceClass) {
    return Result.builder(resourceClass).build();
  }


public class Result<T extends Resource> {

  ...
  //Solution 1
  public static <T2 extends Resource> Builder<T2> builder(T2 instance) {
    return new Builder<T2>();
  }

  // static factory method to get a builder
  // Solution 2
  public static <T2 extends Resource> Builder<T2> builder(Class<T2> clazz) {
    return new Builder<T2>();
  }
  ...
```

Reference: [Object Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--), [Erasure of Generic Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clear and concise answer.  
I added the Solution 2 method and sure enough, now I can invoke that one with `createResult(resource.getClass());` and it no longer complains.
So weird that adding the extra hop appeases the compiler...

Comment: Actually, scratch that, Solution 2 still returns a Result with generic type `Result<? extends Resource>` when I invoke it that way (due to the erasure).  I guess I'd need to add Class<T2> to a number of method signatures in order to get an actual type passed in.  I'm leaning toward just using the constructor directly instead...but with a much better understand now.